# Google Cloud Function with Google Cloud SQL: Python SQLalchemy engine works, but connection fails

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-functions

I have a simple test script to ensure I can connect to and read/write using GCF to Google Cloud SQL instance.

```
def update_db(request):

    import sqlalchemy

    # connect to GCP SQL db
    user = 'root'
    pw = 'XXX'
    conn_name = 'hb-project-319121:us-east4:hb-data'
    db_name = 'Homebase'

    url = 'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@/{}?unix_socket=/cloudsql/{}'.format(user,pw,db_name,conn_name)
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url,pool_size=1,max_overflow=0)

    # Returns
    return f'Success'
```

This is successful but when I try to add a connection:

`conn = engine.connect()`

I get the following error:

`pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'cloudsqlproxy~' (using password: YES)")`

Seems odd that engine can be created but no connection can be made to it? Worth noting that any kind of `execute` using the engine, e.g. `engine.execute('select * from table limit 3')` will also lead to the error above.

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thanks for your time

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: Which IAM roles are assigned to the Cloud Functions service account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `create_engine` method is called, it creates the necessary objects, but does not actually attempt to connect to the database.

[Per the SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html):

> [create_engine] creates a `Dialect` object tailored towards [the database in the connection string], as well as a `Pool` object which will establish a DBAPI connection at [host]:[port] when a connection request is first received.

The error message you receive from MySQL is likely due to the fact that the [special user account for the Cloud SQL Auth proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy#user) has not yet been created.

You need to [create a user in CloudSQL (MySQL)](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-manage-users)  (`'[USER_NAME]'@'cloudsqlproxy~%'` or `'[USER_NAME]'@'cloudsqlproxy~[IP_ADDRESS]'` ).

Comment: That's strange considering I'm able to connect to, read, and write to the db through mysql in python. Only difference here is that I'm attempting to do it through a cloud function as opposed to locally...

Comment: does that change your answer at all or do you think still it's a Cloud SQL Auth proxy issue? The documentation is confusing (aka i'm just stupid), but I'm a bit unsure how to interpret these directions:

`To create a user account for Cloud SQL Auth proxy connections, specify the hostname as 'cloudsqlproxy~[IP_ADDRESS]'. You can also use the IP address wildcard, which would result in 'cloudsqlproxy~%'. The full user account name would be`

So to create a user account, I just have to specify a hostname? What does that mean?